# How to Select from all tables where name = $_POST['name'] in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have several tables in a database which contains DOMAIN NAMES.

I need to run a query which can check whether the DOMAIN NAME is available or not ????

There are different tables e.g. `dotcom`, `dotnet`, `dotcodotuk`, `dotme`, `dotorg` ... etc

Something like this (`SELECT * FROM alltables WHERE name = '$name')`

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Why are they in different tables? They contain the same type of data! You should differentiate between TLDs by using a column in the table, not by splitting the data into multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `union all` on all your table but i'm not sure it is the most efficient way to go (at least it works =) )

```
select domain_name from table1 where nb1_name = 'mydomain.com'
union all
select domain_name from table2 where nb2_name = 'mydomain.com'
union all
[...]
select domain_name from tableN where nb2_name = 'mydomain.com'
```

the query will return one row if the value exists in one of the table

Answer (score 0):

Try [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.

```
select *, 'com' as domain from dotcom where name = '$name'
union all
select * , 'net' as domain from dotnet where name = '$name'
```

Add domain column to know the table that belong the results.

Answer (score -1):

[SQL Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Use SQL Join if the columns values of each tables matches, you did it.